# ElasticSearch cannot find analyzer in field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I create an index like this using a PUT http://localhost:9200/test :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "sortable": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
  }
}
```

This returned:

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Then make sure that the analyzer is there:
http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?_analyzer=sortable&text=HeLLo

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"hello","start_offset":0,"end_offset":5,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0}]}
```

So I create mappings for it:
By PUT http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping/company

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": {
            "analyzer": "sortable"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"no handler for type [{analyzer=sortable}] declared on field [raw]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"no handler for type [{analyzer=sortable}] declared on field [raw]"},"status":400}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `company` mapping needs to be fixed to this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "sortable"
        }
      }
    }
}
```